# convergence of $\sum \sin (k^{-2})$ and $\sum (\sin k^{-k})^{-2}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Test the convergence of the series 
$\sum \sin k^{-2}$
and 
$\sum (\sin k^{-k})^{-2}$.

I'm out of ideas on how to test these series. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Do you mean $(\sin k^{-k})^{-2}$ (which doesn't make sense here) or $(\sin k^{-k})^2$ ?

Comment: @user90369 Why would $(\sin k^{-k})^{-2}$ not make sense?

Comment: @πr8 : $\frac{1}{\sin(k^{-k})}$ is growing (not a null sequence). *Perhaps* it makes sense to ask for a analytic continuation. Anyway, I want to clarify it by the opener of this post.

Comment: @user90369 Noted, though the question as I read it is to test convergence - it's reasonable for the answer to be "it's not convergent". Nevertheless, happy to leave this up to OP.

Comment: @πr8 : It seems to be that the OP meant $(\sin k^{-k})^2$ because he has accepted the answer of *Olivier Oloa*. :-)

Comment: The problem is from Widder's Advanced Calculus and it's written as it is, but I understood it to mean $(\sin k^{-k})^2$. So I guess either it's a typo or the author meant the answer to be divergent because the sequence does not converge to $0$. Anyways thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $k \to \infty$, by using a Taylor series expansion, one gets
$$
\begin{align}
\sin\frac1{k^2}&\sim \frac1{k^2}
\end{align}
$$ and$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sin\frac1{k^k}\right)^2&\sim \frac1{k^{2k}}
\end{align}
$$ then both initial series are *convergent*.